# onClick set href value based on what was clicked

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to find a way to display PHP when I setAttribute to a href. 
This is what I have so far.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('drainage').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('link').setAttribute( 'href', 'Drainage/' <?php echo $conn["area"]; ?> );
        };
    document.getElementById('electrics').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('link').setAttribute( 'href', 'Electrics/' );};}
```

Area = Different towns in UK

So my url should show as www.example.co.uk/Drainage/Bristol

So far it shows just as Drainage or Drainage/Undefined not sure if this is best way to achieve what I want but I have been trying for a while and determined to make it work.

**EDIT**

Drainage and Electrics are modal links that when clicked show a list of towns pulled from a database.

**EXAMPLE**

If drainage was clicked then towns would load and user could then select a town from the list which should then route to that town page but URL should be set as drainage/dynamictown as the drainage link was clicked.

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: Because I am asking how to output a php string into my function ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the function `setAttribute` exists but you could try this instead:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('drainage').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("link").href="YOUR_NEW_LINK"; 
   }
   //Do that for the second button aswell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing there is syntax error in:

```
document.getElementById('link').setAttribute( 'href', 'Drainage/' <?php echo $conn["area"]; ?> );
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById('link').setAttribute( 'href', 'Drainage/<?php echo $conn["area"]; ?>');
```

Second you can achieve it if you load area($conn["area"]) on page load.
You should have area in $conn variable when page loaded.

Like this:

```
<a id="link">Test</a>
<button id="drainage">click</button>
<button id="electrics">click</button>
<?php
$conn["area"] = "Bristol"; // comment this line when you have dynamically
?>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('drainage').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('link').setAttribute( 'href', 'Drainage/<?php echo $conn["area"]; ?>');
    };
    document.getElementById('electrics').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('link').setAttribute( 'href', 'Electrics/' );
    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: Works but $conn["area"] will always be different so we cant have a static value.

Comment: I just show you that you need to have that value when page is loaded. You don't need to assign static data on variable but make sure that you have area in $conn["area"] in $conn variable on that page.